# Django admin - add extra fields using ModelForm of another model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

Is it possible to add extra fields in Django Admin using a ModelForm of another model?

Here my models:

```
class ModelOne(Model):
    field_1_1 = models.SmallIntegerField()
    field_1_2 = models.ForeignKey(AnotherMyModel)
    field_1_3 = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    field_1_4 = models.ManyToManyField(to="TestModel", through="ModelTwo")


class ModelTwo(Model):
    field_2_1 = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_2_2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_2_3 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And the admin looks like:

```
class ModelOneAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ModelOne
    form = forms.ModelTwoForm
    fields = ('field_1_1', 'field_1_2', 'field_1_3', 'field_2_1', 'field_2_3')
```

Here the form instead:

```
class ModelTwoForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelTwo
        fields = "__all__"
```

This code raises the following error:

```
FieldError: Unknown field(s) (field_2_1) specified for ModelOneAdmin
```

I know that this is the case of the inline pattern, but i cannot use it becasue ModelOneAdmin is already inside a inline model (and i don't want to include extra python package to achieve this).

Is there a way to fix this problem and achieve this goal?

(Working with Python2.7 and Django 1.11)

Comment: You can rather try extending `class ModelOneAdmin(admin.TabularInline, ModelTwo)`, then you will have all the fields of model two in model one admin